# Matrix-vector multiplication for only one dimension in a tensor

Tags: pytorch

Is it possible to multiply only one (last) dimension in a tensor alone with other vectors?

For example, assume a tensor T=[100, 20, 400] and a matrix M =[400, 400]. 
Is it possible to make the operation `h_{transpose}*M*h`, where `h` is the last dimension in the tensor T? In other words, is it possible to make use of (possibly pytorch) built-in functions to get the resulting tensor of size [100, 20, 1]?

Comment: From the matrix `M`, how should the vector of shape `[400, 1]` chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest (certainly the shortest) solution is with [`einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.einsum).

```
import torch

T = torch.randn(100, 20, 400)
M = torch.randn(400, 400)

res = torch.einsum('abc,cd,abd->ab', (T, M, T)).unsqueeze(-1)
```

It basically says "for all `(a, b, c, d)` in bounds, multiply `T[a, b, c]` with `M[c, d]` and `T[a, b, d]` and accumulate it in `res[a, b]`".

Since `einsum` is implemented in terms of basic building blocks like [`mm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.mm), `transpose` etc, this could certainly be unrolled into a more "classical" solution, but right now my brain fails me at that.